# How to apply a custom style/template to a treeviewItem in xaml

Tags: wpf, templates, xaml, treeview

So I have editted the TreeViewItem template, (so that I could get rid of the checkbox).

I was just wondering how I can apply this template to my treeview...The Treeview is databound.

is it something like:

```
<TreeView>
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
....
...
```

?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`ItemContainerStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx) of the `TreeView`. Or apply it implicitly by having it defined in the resources with only the `TargetType` set (this could be superior as the `ItemContainerStyle` may only affect the root items).

Comment: could you elaborate on the second part (applying it implicitly) please? I am new to wpf :(

Comment: Then i'd rather point you to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx), if you must, search for *implicit* and you should find an explanaition, but i would recommend reading the whole thing...